# cookie information is logged as ellipsis in IIS logs?

Tags: iis, logging, cookies, web

We are dealing with some strange issues while analyzing IIS logs for our web sites. The problem is that I see many entries in the log files when the cookie information is logged as ellipsis, see the sample entry below:

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 6.0
```

## Version: 1.0

## Date: 2013-01-25 08:00:00

## Fields: date time s-sitename s-computername cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query cs-username c-ip cs-version cs(User-Agent) cs(Cookie) cs(Referer) cs-host sc-status sc-substatus sc-bytes cs-bytes time-taken

```
2013-01-25 08:01:11 W3SVC1443552327 IRC-P2WEB-031 GET /pm/free-data-report-faq/Default.aspx SiteVersionID=988&SiteID=100219&Status=A&sc=674104&bcd=SiteVersionID=988&SiteID=100219&Status=A&sc=674104&bcd= - 24.7.1.77 HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(iPhone;+CPU+iPhone+OS+6_0+like+Mac+OS+X)+AppleWebKit/536.26+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Version/6.0+Mobile/10A405+Safari/8536.25 **...** https://member.some-site.com/PM/reports/credit/articles/about-data-reports www.some-site.com 200 0 14841 6748 62
```

as you can see the cookie information is shown as ellipsis. Is there any way to find out why this happens and to prevent this?  We rely on cookie analysis to get the session id as well as other important data for our web analytics and missing such crucial piece of data is real problem for us.

Thank you for your help in advance,

Answer (score 1):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2809913

IIS will omit the cookie information if it exceeds 4096 bytes.  Microsoft suggests that if you don't like this behaviour, you should write your own request logger or make the cookies shorter.